# Jquery Dialog with asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

When i click on button to show the message i get one MessageBox that's normal but when i call the Jquery Dialog for the SCOND time i get two MessageBoxs! and when i call Jquery Dialog for the third time i get three MessageBoxs! Please help me!

Here is my Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id*=Call_Dialog]").click(function() {

                $("#MyDiv").dialog({
                    title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#ShowMessage").click(function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('Hi');
                    $("#MyDiv").dialog('close');
                })
            })
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MyDiv" style="display: none">

<asp:Button ID="ShowMessage" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 

    </div>



    </form>
    <p>
        <input id="Call_Dialog" type="button" value="button" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `.dialog()` and `.click()` inside `$("[id*=Call_Dialog]").click()` event. Is this what you meant to do?

Comment: No, the problem is when i call the Jquery Dialog for the SCOND time i get two MessageBoxs! and when i call Jquery Dialog for the third time i get three MessageBoxs!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with ASP.NET just so you know.

Comment: @Lucy have updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but how can i call the dialog with button click?

Dialog should be initialized only once not every time you click on something and regenerate

solution is put dialog initialization outside of click and you're done

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#MyDiv").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });

 $("[id*=Call_Dialog]").click(function() {
   $("#ShowMessage").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('Hi');
                $("#MyDiv").dialog('close');
            })
        })
    });
```

to open jquery dialog : use this overload :

```
$("#MyDiv").dialog('open');
```